# Reflection for validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, reflection

```
CustomerValidator: AbstractValidator<Customer>
```

How might one dynamically instantiate the class above if passed an instance of a Customer??
Similarly if I had:

```
Cat c = new Cat();
```

I would want to dynamically invoke the class that implements

```
AbstractValidator<Cat>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One common approach (if you own both `Customer` and `CustomerValidator`) is to decorate the class with the class that provides validation, via an attribute:

```
[Validator(typeof(CustomerValidator))]
public class Customer { }
```

Note that you may find it easier to work *outside* of generics, perhaps via an interface (note: no methods etc shown here):

```
public interface IValidator { }
public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer> {}
public class AbstractValidator<T> : IValidator where T : class {}
```

Then obtain the correct validator via reflection:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ValidatorAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type ValidatorType { get; private set; }
    public ValidatorAttribute(Type validatorType)
    {
        ValidatorType = validatorType;
    }
    public static IValidator GetValidator(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return null;
        return GetValidator(obj.GetType());
    }
    public static IValidator GetValidator(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null) return null;
        ValidatorAttribute va = (ValidatorAttribute)
            Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(type, typeof(ValidatorAttribute));
        if (va == null || va.ValidatorType == null) return null;
        return (IValidator) Activator.CreateInstance(va.ValidatorType);
    }
}
```

So calling `GetValidator` should return `null` or a suitable `IValidator`.

You can use generics in the above - but it usually creates more problems than it solves in example like this.

Comment: No problem - any problems, post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to refer to a Solution Proposed by **[Imaar Spaanjaars](http://imar.spaanjaars.com)** which he has provided in a series of articles he wrote for "**[N-Layered Web Applications with ASP.NET 3.5](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=476)**". The [Part 2](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=477) of the series has the solution to exactly what you require. I have successfully implemented this solution in my Model and it's working absolutely perfect.

Here's the Link:

[link text](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=477)

Also refer [Part 3](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=478) which discusses advanced scenrio for Validations.